# trouble with the required property of HTML5 and a javascript function

Tags: javascript, properties, required

I have a form that depending on the option you select show or hide a div.

In this div I have two elements input.

If the div is set to be dislayed I have a function that add the attribute required true.

If it is set to not be displayed it is not display but it say to me

An invalid form control with name='montant_creance' is not focusable. index.php:1
An invalid form control with name='condition2' is not focusable.

But I really do not understand why because the div is set to display none.

Here is the function I use

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function addattribute()
{
    if (document.getElementById('montant').style.display == "block")
    {
        document.getElementsByName('montant_creance')[1].setAttribute('required');
        document.getElementsByName('condition2')[0].setAttribute('required');
    }

}
</script>
```

So Can anyone explain me why it show me this message in the console? 
I've tried using that function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addattribute()
{
    if (document.getElementById('montant').style.display == "block")
    {
        document.getElementsByName('montant_creance')[0].setAttribute('required');
        document.getElementsByName('condition2')[0].setAttribute('required');
    }
    if (document.getElementById('montant').style.display == "none")
    {
        document.getElementsByName('montant_creance')[0].setAttribute('required','false');
        document.getElementsByName('condition2')[0].setAttribute('required','false');
    }
}
</script>
```

it say often

An invalid form control with name='montant_creance' is not focusable. index.php:1
An invalid form control with name='condition2' is not focusable.

I also tried adding some input type hidden; using that function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addattribute()
{
    if (document.getElementById('montant').style.display == "block")
    {
        document.getElementsByName('montant_creance')[1].setAttribute('required');
        document.getElementsByName('condition2')[1].setAttribute('required');
    }
    if (document.getElementById('montant').style.display == "none")
    {
        document.getElementsByName('montant_creance')[0].setAttribute('required','false');
        document.getElementsByName('condition2')[0].setAttribute('required','false');
    }
}
</script>
```

here is the preview :
http://jsfiddle.net/VUZQP/

Receive all my utmost Respect

Answer (score 1):

Calling `.setAttribute()` with only one parameter will set the attribute to "false", effectively.  You really shouldn't be using `setAttribute()` at all:

```
document.getElementsByName('montant_creance')[1].required = true; // or false
```

Most attributes from HTML are implemented as *properties* of DOM elements, and there's no need to access them with `.setAttribute()`.  They're directly properties of the objects, and should be treated as such.